# the app craches when changing the bitmap of image to uri

Tags: android

I've written a program(in android studio)that takes a picture when a button is clicked and that picture is sent automatically to Firebase storage. it was working fine, but when I take a picture it has a very low resolution. I was using the bitmap for that and I found that it is the reason so I changed it to uri. But I'm sure I did something wrong when changing the code to uri, because now when I take the picture it has a full resolution which is great but the app crashes before it sent the picture to the firebase storage. 
here is my code :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;
    private Button Sbutton;
    private StorageReference mStorageRef;
    Uri image;
    String mCameraFileName;
    private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
        StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build());
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        //Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intent.setAction(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        Date date = new Date();
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("-mm-ss");

        String newPicFile = df.format(date) + ".jpg";
        String outPath = "/sdcard/" + newPicFile;
        File outFile = new File(outPath);

        mCameraFileName = outFile.toString();
        Uri outuri = Uri.fromFile(outFile);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outuri);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
       if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
           startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
       //    startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

       }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
        Sbutton = findViewById(R.id.Tbutton);
        Sbutton.setOnClickListener(this);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        dispatchTakePictureIntent();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == 2) {
                ImageSwitcher imageView = null;
                if (data != null) {
                    image = data.getData();
                    imageView.setImageURI(image);
                    imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    uploadFile(image);
                }
                if (image == null && mCameraFileName != null) {
                    image = Uri.fromFile(new File(mCameraFileName));
                    imageView.setImageURI(image);
                    imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                File file = new File(mCameraFileName);
                if (!file.exists()) {
                    file.mkdir();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private <imageView> void uploadFile(imageView image) {
        StorageReference mountainImagesRef = mStorageRef.child("images/" + String.valueOf(SystemClock.currentThreadTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      //  image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
        byte[] data = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
        UploadTask uploadTask = mountainImagesRef.putBytes(data);
        uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                // Handle unsuccessful uploads
            }
        }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                        Log.d("downloadUrl-->", "" + task.getResult());
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Uploading Image Done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: please add the logcat of the crash.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar use-case like you have.

Please look at my solution that I've shared below:

```
String filePath;//Path of the file where image is stored

//Capture Image via camera
private void dispatchTakePictureIntent(int requestCode) {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File photoFile = createImageFile(requestCode);
            Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                    FILE_PROVIDER_AUTHORITY,
                    photoFile);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
            // Workaround for Android bug.
            // grantUriPermission also needed for KITKAT,
            // see https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=76683
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                List<ResolveInfo> resInfoList = activity.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(takePictureIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
                for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resInfoList) {
                    String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
                    activity.grantUriPermission(packageName, photoURI, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                }
            }
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, requestCode);
        }
    }

//create image file
private File createImageFile(int requestCode) {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("-mm-ss", Locale.ENGLISH).format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = new File(storageDir, imageFileName + ".jpg");
    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    filePath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}

private void uploadImage() {
    Uri file = Uri.fromFile(new File(filePath));
    final StorageReference storageReference = storageRef.child("docs/" + 
            mobileNumber + "/" + file.getLastPathSegment());
    UploadTask uploadTask = storageReference.putFile(file);

    uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
            @Override
            public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                    throw task.getException();
                }

                return storageReference.getDownloadUrl();
            }
        }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();
                    Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: downloadUri: " + downloadUri.toString());
            }
        });
    }
```